# Method 'getValue' to get the value of a checkbox/radioButton/textBox in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am implementing a method 'getValue' (return type needed is String) in java to get the value of a checkbox/radioButton/textBox using webdriver as below:

```
             try {
        element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(target));
        BoolResult = element.isSelected();
        if(BoolResult==true) {
            result="Radio Button/textbox Selected";
            return result;
        } else if(BoolResult==false){
            result="Radio Button/textbox Not Selected";
            return result;
        } else {

        }
    } catch(Exception e2) {

    }
            try {

        element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(target));
        result = element.getAttribute("value");
         log.info("The value of the target is : " + result);
         } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug(e);
        return result;
    }
```

The above is working fine for Radio Button, but for TextBox, its going to the BoolResult==false condition and saying that 'RadioButton/TextBox Not selected', whereas i am expecting it to go to the next try block and execute the 'element.getAttribute("value")'.

Can someone please help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine whether the element is a checkbox or textbox. You should use more specific xpaths so that you know what you're dealing with before getting to this point, but anyways, this should work (it's untested though):

```
element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(target));

string type = element.getAttribute("type");

if (type.equals("checkbox") {
  if(element.isSelected()) {
    result="Radio Button/textbox Selected";
  } else {
    result="Radio Button/textbox Not Selected";
}
else if (type.equals("text")) {
  result = element.getAttribute("value");
}
else {
  log.debug("Unexpected input type");
}
return result;
```

Comment: This is working perfectly fine. The new point I found here is to determine whether the element is a checkbox/radio/textbox by using 'element.getAttribute("type")'. It made my task easy.. Thank You..